# Как следует проверять или ограничивать длину строки, введённой в произвольное текстовое поле, при отправке на сервер?

Tags: строки, post, веб-сервер, память

Допустим, есть какой-то web-сервис. Он должен получить от клиента некоторую строку. Она не какая-то особенная с точки зрения формата, не нужны никакие регулярные выражения. Вообще говоря, не так важно, будет там 10 символов или 10 тысяч символов.

Однако память в любом случае ограничена. Соответственно, если можно послать строку неограниченной длины, в теории может произойти такое, что памяти для хранения не хватит.

Нашёл, что для POST-запроса можно установить в `php.ini` лимит. Тогда может быть и не стоит переживать за введённые данные? Если что, будет ошибка.

Так как следует поступать правильно? Нужно ли проверять на длину любые полученные данные перед записью?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря куда ты их собираешься записывать. Если в базу, то надо смотреть сколько можно записать в колонки, если 200 символов, то когда строка будет 250 символов, лишнее обрежется. Но если тебе важно чтоб ничего не обрезалось, то надо проверять.